# Unit testing for PHP 5.1 without Phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, refactoring, legacy-code

I'm dealing with legacy code from php 5.1 and I need to fix or refactor the code. I'm trying to install Phpunit 3.4 and I found this lib but I can't find the dependencies so maybe thats not the best solution...

Is there any legacy distro image that includes these libraries or there is any way to archive this unit testing with PHP 5.1?

Comment: what do you means about dependencies ?

Comment: Phpunit dependencies to get it working correctly as the 3.4 version was managed through PEAR.

Comment: You can't find manually dependencies libraries PEAR ?